# How to control webkit frame on Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a CSS slider that does not slide, only when forward and backward link is click  which will be done in jquery however I am not sure how to call the element webkitframe in jquery

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim_slides {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  6% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uxwde7tL/1/

Comment: Have you tried bootstraps carousel?
This is exactely what it does :D

Here is a quick example:
[carousel](https://jsfiddle.net/f37bbs77/)

Edit: to stop the autoplay just add interval:false in js:
[carouselV2](https://jsfiddle.net/f37bbs77/1/)

Comment: thanks almost there does carousel support fade effect, I want to make it not like look like a slider but a pic with steady image changing on click

Comment: [carouselV3](https://jsfiddle.net/f37bbs77/2/)

Here is something i tried... is this what u are looking for?

Comment: thanks one last question, how do I control the slider similar to a thumbnail but want to display link instead of thumbnail so for example I have 10 sliders and just 3 links https://jsfiddle.net/f37bbs77/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like my comment was what you'r looking for. :)

According to your last question:
I added 2 `onClick` functions to slide to the next or the previous slide.

Here is the resulting fiddle:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f37bbs77/4/)

For further carousel functions, please have a look at:
[Bootstrap Carousel](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#carouselnumber)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot control `keyframes` with jQuery (or JS) directly as you wanted.

what you can do with jQuery set the animation for certain CSS property, it is `opacity` in your case, and change the value of it by JS and that way you will loose the `%` control of the animation.

or you can use `Timeout` function and set the animation class to object, assuming you know when it should change. You set the animation class, with timeout middle of the animation change the image url and then end of the animation remove the animation class.